# MySQL define 1 result as text from SELECT query

Tags: mysql, excel

Using:  **MySQL Workbench** & **MySQL for Excel**

I have a number returned that is 12 digits long, however when imported in to excel using any manner this results in:  1.20523E+11.

I want (need) to specify that the value needs to be returned as text so to complete the query via MySQL for Excel without this error.

My existing query:

```
Select  
    -- Get Order data --
        T5.orders_id As OID,                                                                                                                                      
        DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, '%Y-%m-%d') As ODate,                                                
        T3.products_name As PName,                                                                                                      
        T3.products_id As PID,  

        error:                                                                                                          
        DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased,'%y%m%d%H%i%s') As DecRepID,
            -- This results in 1503070244
            -- Transaction ID to match with Payments
```

I need the `1503070244` to return as `TEXT` so excel imports it without me needing to then convert the text.

I've looked at `CONVERT` & `CAST` however I can't get the query to work correctly & they resolve in to syntax errors.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),(DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased,'%y%m%d%H%i%s'))) As DecRepID,
```

`CAST` returns the correct values, however Excel doesn't recognise as text.

```
cast(DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased,'%y%m%d%H%i%s') as char) As DecRepID
```

I know it's something simple, however I can't find what is the cause of the error.

Is there a way to correct this through code, or am I stuck with post-formatting after import in to Excel?

Thank you.

Comment: I dont know mysql. Try prefixing the output with an apostrophe character (`'`) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the idea that Shahkalpesh had, you could do 2 different things:

1)  You could try `escaping` the `'` by using:  `'\''`

```
concat('\'', DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased,'%y%m%d%H%i%s')) As DecRepID,
```

2)  You could try `escaping` the `'` by using: `"'"`

```
concat("'", DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased,'%y%m%d%H%i%s')) As DecRepID,
```

By escaping the `'` the column will import in to Excel as:  `'1503070244` which is what you will need to have Excel recognise it as text to stop the shortened result.

You can read more here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html